# Test for significance of correlation matrix

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

If one wishes to test if the correlations in a correlation matrix are statistically significant as a whole group, one can perform a likelihood ratio test of the hypothesis that the correlation matrix is equal to the identity matrix.

The ratio of the restricted and unrestricted likelihood functions is $\alpha = |R|^{N/2}$ , where |R| is the determinant of the correlation matrix (Morrison, 1967).

The test statistic is therefore $-2\log(\alpha)$, which is distributed as $\chi^2$ with $\frac{1}{2}p(p-1)$ df.

**My question is, how do you perform the calculation of the observed value $-2\log( \alpha)$?**

Comment: The question asks about alpha, the final line about lambda. I might be missing something, but is this a typo? (Or am I just confused?)

Comment: It was supposed to be −2log(a), edited it.

Comment: Would it be possible to define a few more of the variables (N, p)? N is sample size for each correlation?  Is Morrison, 1967 available online?  Is there another reference I could read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

in R:

```
R <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.1, 0.1, 
            0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 
            0.1, 0.1, 1.0), nrow=3)
N <- 100

chi <- -2*log(det(R)^(N/2))
df <- nrow(R)*(nrow(R)-1)/2
p <- 1 - pchisq(chi, df)  
chi
p
```

Or in Excel:
Where the matrix is in cells C26:E28, and N is 100:

```
=-2*(LN(MDETERM(C26:E28)^100/2))
```

And the above is in cell D31:

```
=CHIDIST(D31,3)
```

You can also use the sem package:

```
require(sem)  
rownames(R)  <- c("a", "b", "c")
colnames(R)  <- c("a", "b", "c")
mySem <- specifyModel()
  a <-> a, va, NA
  b <-> b, vb, NA
  c <-> c, vc, NA

semFit <- sem(mySem, S=R, N=100)  
summary(semFit)
```

(sem gives a very slightly different answer, because it multiplies by N-1).

Comment: This is it, thank you Jeremy. I used R, worked fine.

Comment: When applying this to a correlation matrix, the determinant is zero.  Eg: `test.values <- matrix(data=rnorm(1000),nrow=10)
test.cor <- cor(test.values)  

cor.sig.test(test.cor, N=100)`  Is there a way to test for significance of such a correlation matrix (other than some permutation test)?

Comment: For the previous comment: `cor.sig.test <- function(cor.matrix, N){
    chi <- -2*log(det(cor.matrix)^(N/2))
    df <- nrow(cor.matrix)*(nrow(cor.matrix)-1)/2
    p <- 1 - pchisq(chi, df)
    print℗
}`